# StarCraft2: maps for placement matches

Tags: starcraft-2

Do maps for placement matches contain barriers that prevent rush?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. All ranked games use the standard maps. The "Novice" versions of maps (which have destructible rocks to stop early rushes) are only used in the practice league.